Проблема с маршрутизацией HashRouter на хостинге nic.ru
Есть сайт на React, который использует маршрутизацию React-router-dom, сначала на localhost я использовал BrowserRouter, всё работало нормально.
При деплое на хостинг (nic.ru), маршрутизация BrowserRouter перестала работать. При переходе по ссылкам они были недоступны (404 ошибка).
Я почитал и заменил BrowserRouter на HashRouter. Но это маршрутизация с # в ссылке просто ужасная, но всё работало, кроме того, что при индексации гугл и яндекс роботов, они тоже ругались на недоступные страницы (в которых имелся # в ссылке).
Так вот, как можно реализовать BrowserRouter на статическом хостинге (nic.ru), или ещё может быть какие-нибудь решения?
